# NSArray mutability and arrayByAddingObject

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I thought I had a good understanding of Objects and mutability in Objective-C but I've noticed something curious with `NSArray`.

If I have the following that doesn't work:

```
NSArray *myArray = [ [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:someKey] arrayByAddingObject:myObject ];
```

**"myObject" is never added to "myArray"**.

However, the following works:

```
NSArray *someArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:someKey];
NSArray *myArray = [someArray arrayByAddingObject:myObject];
```

What's the explanation for this? I know that `NSArray` is not mutable but since it is during the initial assignment, it should work since either way seems equivalent.

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:someKey]` returns an `NSArray`

someArray is an `NSArray`

And so, an `NSArray` is derived simply from `[NSArray arrayByAddingObject:Object]`

Thanks!

EDIT 1

I am simply wanting to store the `NSArray` back to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myArray forKey:someKey];
```

It was never storing it properly, and so when I debugged I saw that "myObject" was never being added when the array was created.

*Note: I have only been testing with `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:someKey]` returning a empty/`nil` array*

EDIT 2

I've isolated the issue a bit; **this only happens if `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:someKey]` returns "nil"** (basically, the array doesn't exist in `NSUserDefaults`).
I'm still curious to know though why it's not an issue for the 2nd code solution I have.

Comment: The two expressions are identical.  Define "doesn't work";  i.e. paste examples of how you tested it.

Comment: I've added more detail of how I am using the NSArray after assignment.

Comment: The two expressions are identical;  if NSUserDefaults returns `nil`, then `myArray` will always be `nil`.  If that isn't the case, it is either because NSUserDefaults is returning a non-nil value when you think it is `nil` or you haven't shown us all the code.

Comment: for me your first solution works well, if the array has been set previously.

Answer (score 0):

How are you checking to see if `myObject` is ever added? Both code examples look fine, and I've certainly used the former with no issues. But all of your assumptions are correct. The issue, if indeed there is one, lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

That should be the expected behaviour

If you call a method on `nil` in Objective-C, you always get nil (or NO/0) as your return value

In this case, when calling `NSArray *myArray = [ [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:someKey] arrayByAddingObject:myObject ];`, if `someKey` isn't set in `NSUserDefaults`, then you're calling `[nil arrayByAddingObject:]` and so would expect to get `nil` back